# pscp is not recognized as an internal or external command error

Tags: command-line, batch, putty

I have a batch file with a query like `pscp ....` written in it. When i try to run that file an error pops up saying `pscp is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or a batch file`. On my computer, `putty.exe` is located at `C:\Putty`. I've this path to the environmental variables and still facing the same error.

Need some help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can put the files in c:\putty but make sure that the location is in your path.  Otherwise you will still have the same problem.

1. Right click on my computer
2. Click on properties
3. In the system properties window click on the advanced tab
4. In the advanced section click the environment variables button.
5. Highlight path and add what you need to your path variable.

[image: Screen shot of where path can be altered. Credit to the original file owner.]

Answer (score 1):

`pscp` is the [PuTTY Secure Copy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) program for Windows, analogous to `scp` on UNIX-type systems. It allows you to securely copy files using the [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) protocol.

Download the file from the link above, put it in your `C:\Putty` directory, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should download all the file associated with putty not only "putty.exe" from the below link:
[A .ZIP file containing all the binaries (except PuTTYtel), and also the help files](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.zip)